# LDAP Query Failure due to single quote

Tags: ldap, quotes

I'm trying to find an employee in Active Directory using the following c# code:

```
"Select userPrincipalName, ADsPath, Department, Mail,
 HomeMDB, cn, ssn FROM 
'LDAP://" + DomainName + "'
WHERE objectCategory = 'person' and 
sAMAccountName = '" + UserName.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

When I run this for an employee with a single quote in the last name (such as "O'Connor") I get the following error:

**AdsDsoObject' failed with no error message available, result code: DB_E_NOTABLE(0x80040E37).**

```
I also tried Replace("'", "\''"), nothing is working.
```

What am I doing wrong? need help.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Do the replace on it's own line.

```
Username.Replace("'", "\'");

"Select userPrincipalName, ADsPath, Department, Mail, HomeMDB, cn, ssn FROM 
'LDAP://" + DomainName + "' WHERE objectCategory = 'person' and 
sAMAccountName = '" + UserName + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

```
Replace("'", "\''")
```

And not:

```
Replace("'", "\'")
```

(There's an extra single quote in there).